# what does mean arguments of .ajaxError(function(event,xhr,options,exc))

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been using the `error()` Ajax Event in `$.ajax()` and `$.ajaxSetup()` that have three arguments: `error(xhr,status,error)` i know what is these arguments and don't problem with it.

But cannot understand the arguments of `.ajaxError(function(event,xhr,options,exc))`**.** Can any one describe these arguments, each of the four. specially `event` argument. and can give me an example that to use each of the four arguments of `.ajaxError(function(event,xhr,options,exc))`

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discussed my question in JQuery Forums and get a useful [answer](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/what-does-mean-arguments-of-ajaxerror-function-event-xhr-options-exc#14737000003991067) **:**

`event is an ajaxError event object and doesn't contain any particularly useful information. xhr is the jQuery wrapper around the XMLHttpRequest object that made the request - useful attributes are status and statusText. options is the full set of options sent to the ajax request - useful attributes are url, isLocal, and type. exc is the exception thrown - useful attributes are filename and message, and possibly lineNumber and columnNumber.`

```
$('#results').ajaxError(function(event, xhr, options, exc) {
  $(this).text('Couldn\'t load ' + options.url + ' because (' +
        xhr.status + ' - ' + xhr.statusText + ') ' + exc.message);
});
```

And in addition studied `The Event Object (page 173)` section of `JavaScript & jQuery: The Missing Manual, 2nd Edition` book. Amount of the section is:

**The Event Object**
`Whenever a web browser fires an event, it records information about the event and
stores it in an event object. The event object contains information that was collected
when the event occurred, like the vertical and horizontal coordinates of the mouse,
the element on which the event occurred, or whether the Shift key was pressed when
the event was triggered.`

And now know what that didn't understand. **Just one thing:**

Can anyone give me explicitly several instances of `$.ajaxError event(parameter) attributes.`
I do debugging  with `Firebug` and look at `event Object` and found very useful information, but i'm newbie and need some features which are correct for my article about `$.ajaxError parameters.`

Comment: You can (and should) accept your own answer.  FYI, it was helpful to me.